# c# md5 to be the same as PHPs md5 hash

Tags: c#, md5

I'm going a bit crazy with this! I'm trying to authenticate my app against an existing database (so I can't change the PHP side) and I need to convert my password field to be the same as php's md5(moo) command.

However, each formula I try to create the hash comes up with the same md5 has, very different to whats in the database.

Is there a formula that produces the same results?

I've tried:

```
 public static string MbelcherEncodePassword(string originalPassword)
        {
            Byte[] originalBytes;
            Byte[] encodedBytes;
            MD5 md5;

            // Conver the original password to bytes; then create the hash
            md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(originalPassword);
            encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

            // Bytes to string
            return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes), "-", "").ToLower();


        }
```

And:

```
public static string MD5(string password)
        {
            byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
            try
            {
                System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider cryptHandler;
                cryptHandler = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] hash = cryptHandler.ComputeHash(textBytes);
                string ret = "";
                foreach (byte a in hash)
                {
                    if (a < 16)
                        ret += "0" + a.ToString("x");
                    else
                        ret += a.ToString("x");
                }
                return ret;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and:

```
 public static string MD5Hash(string text)
            {
                System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text))), "-", "");
            }
```

To no avail. Any help really will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why `ASCIIEncoding`? PHP is likely to be using UTF-8 for input, so use `UTF8Encoding` as well. Although that should not matter for "test" passwords...

Comment: 1. Check whether the existing application uses a salt. It probably does (though, given that the application uses MD5 for password hashing, I cannot bet on it) - please see [Everything you wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) for more information about password storage; 2. Is the character set for passwords limited to (a subset of) ASCII?

Comment: Also, "what's in the database" is irrelevant. The PHP code might be writing random bytes in the database each time, would you be able to match its behavior by looking at the results? You need to look at the code.

Comment: Wait... you're using md5 for your password hash! The horror! md5 is really bad for that, not secure at all :(

Comment: Also: post the php you're using, and a sample input/output pair.

Answer (score 1):

Following should give you same hex string as PHP md5:

```
public string GetMd5Hex(MD5 crypt, string input)
{
    return crypt.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))
        .Select<byte, string>(a => a.ToString("x2"))
        .Aggregate<string>((a, b) => string.Format("{0}{1}", a, b));
}
```